# WPF Open URL in browser with credentials

Tags: wpf, internet-explorer, credentials

How can I open up a URL in a new browser window which is protected by a username/password dialog and auto-populate these fields (or even better pass the credentials to the browser)?

NOTE I need to open it up in a new browser window, **not** a WPF WebControl.

At the moment I'm using the `LaunchUriOrFileAction` which works fine in opening up a new browser window, but I need the credentials populated automatically.

The default browser will be IE8 for the client. So the old way of `http://user:pass@example.com` wont work.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The following solution uses the WebBrowser control to open a new IE browser window. It works but there are several limitiations:

- Obviously, it can only open IE -- this will not work if you want it to open Firefox
- The new browser window appears in the background, with a flashing button in the taskbar
- The browser doesn't actually remember the credentials, so users will get prompted if they attempt to navigate to another password-protected page

---

```
void OpenIEToAuthenticatedUrl(string url, string username, string password)
{
  using (WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser()) {
    string userPass = username + ":" + password;
    string encodedUserPass = Convert.ToBase64String(
      Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(userPass)
    );

    browser.Navigate(
      url,
      Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), // Force a new window by passing a unique frame name
      null, // No POST data
      "Authorization: Basic " + encodedUserPass
    );
  }
}

...

OpenIEToAuthenticatedUrl(
  "http://example.com/", 
  "user", "pass"
);
```

Comment: thanks, its at least a start, the IE issue is fine, but the background window is a problem